# How to implement the view like App Store top view

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

In the App Store app, the top section of view rotates a picture in about every 10 seconds.  How to implement such behavior?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: At least try something before asking a question. Research UIScrollViews with paging.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at KASlideShow, its an basic Slideshow for IOS. i this that's what you are looking for. Good luck :)

KASlideShow at Github:
https://github.com/kirualex/KASlideShow

Answer (score 0):

I'd say go with a `UICollectionView`, `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` with its `scrollDirection` property set to `UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal` and `pagingEnabled` set to `YES`.